# Ad-block for Spotify?

Tags: windows, ad-blocker, spotify

Is there an ad-blocker solution for [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/) that blocks ads and gets rid of the audio ads rather than mutes them?

Currently I am using [EZBlocker](http://www.ericzhang.me/projects/spotify-ad-blocker-ezblocker/) but it only mutes the audio ads which I find extremely annoying and instead I hear long long pauses between my songs and the normal banner ads are still there.

Is there an ad-blocker (like completely gets rid of ads + audio ads) for Spotify on Windows so I can listen to uninterrupted music?

I would pay for it, but at moment I would rather listen to free music, just without the ads. It's great that Spotify allows free music streaming on desktop and all but I think this is just a ploy to get more people to use it rather than [Rdio](http://www.rdio.com/) which offers free streaming of music as well.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You could think about using [Spotify Premium](https://www.spotify.com/premium/). As it is the non-free product offered by Spotify itself, it is not really an ad-blocker, but it does give you what you want. You won´t get any ads, and you pay very little compared to the large wealth of music offered. You mentioned that you would also pay for an ad-blocker.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the web player of spotify (accessible via https://play.spotify.com/) with Chrome, the Plugin Adblock Plus automatically removes / skips (anyway: you won't hear them) the sound ads between songs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a program that doesn’t mute the Ads but removes them entirely. It works by blocking the IP’s from the Ad servers and it isn’t running in the background, you start it once and it adds the IP’s to the windows firewall. Works great for me :)

http://spotifyadkiller.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

So, it's still somewhere between beta and release, but I've developed something that is basically "adblock plus" at the packet level. That means you can apply adblock plus filters and CSS selectors to **any program running on your computer**. All content fetched over HTTP/HTTPS is forced through the filter, beyond the knowledge or intervention of the software that is being filtered.

It's called Stahp It, it's 100% free and open source, and you can download the appropriate version for your PC [here](https://github.com/TechnikEmpire/StahpIt-WPF/releases).